# Interactions between 2 forms (hide/show)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two WinForm objects, `form1` and `form2`. What I want to do is:

a. When the user clicks a button on `form1`, this will get hidden and a new instance of `form2` will show up. So I did:

```
form1.Hide();
form2 new_session = new form2();
form2.Show();
```

b. From `form2`, I would like the user to be able to click a button to recover  the originary `form1` from which he has generated the `form2` instance. Basically, something like:

```
form2.Hide();
form1.Show();
```

Clearly, `form1` does not exist in the current context. The solution I know to work around this problem is to create a property of `form2` where I assign the `form1`, so that I can call it back again:

```
form1 pMyForm;
public form1 myForm
{
get{return pMyForm;}
set{pMyForm = value;}
}
```

and before to show the `form2`...

```
form2 new_session = new form2();
form2.myForm = this;
```

However, I feel like there's a more proper way of doing this. I thought I could have found the `form1` into the property `ParentForm` of `form2`, but I find a `null` instead. At the same time, I've tried to assign `form1` to the property `Parent` of `form2` but I get the error `Top-level control cannot be added to a control`.

Do you have any suggestion on how to better handle this problem?

Comment: This might help you!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273862/c-sharp-how-to-make-two-forms-reference-each-other

Comment: You already know how to do this since you already used the universal solution to this problem.  That button you added to Form2 knows how to run code inside your Form2 class.  But the Button class does not know anything about your Form2 class.  Just do it the exact same way: raise an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Form2.Owner = this;
```

And

```
Form1 form = (Form1)this.Owner;
```

See my full answer here:
[how to exit from application on click of (red X ) button right top on winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043968/how-to-exit-from-application-on-click-of-red-x-button-right-top-on-winform/31044031#31044031)